# Blazor Some services are not able to be constructed

Tags: c#, blazor

Hello I'm fairly new to Blazor and cannot seem to figure out why I keep getting this error: AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: TranactionJournalV4.Data.SearchService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: TranactionJournalV4.Data.SearchService': Unable to resolve service for type 'TranactionJournalV4.Data.SqlDbContext' while attempting to activate 'TranactionJournalV4.Data.SearchService'.)

Here is my SearchService that I have made which would take an input date and search my database

```
 public class SearchService
    {
        private readonly SqlDbContext _context;

        public SearchService(SqlDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("search")]
        public async Task<List<TransactionModel>> SearchTransactionsAsync(DateTime transactionDate)
        {
            return await _context.TransactionJournal.Where(s => s.TransactionDateTime.Date <= transactionDate.Date).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the lifetime of SearchService (i.e.please provide the registration code in the DI container)?

Comment: @boindiil This is what I have in the di container services.AddSingleton<SearchService>(); unless I am mistaken

Comment: Then your problem is, that you cannot inject a transient or scoped service into a singleton service.

Comment: @boindiil Thanks. I tried using addtransient and addscoped but I still had the same problem

Comment: How is your SqlDbContext registered?

Comment: @boindiil This is how i registered my dbcontext services.AddDbContext<SqlDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. my searchservice had to be used as a transient in DI